# Iterate over Vaadin Table Rows

Tags: vaadin

I have a Vaadin Table with some Filters and sorts. Is it possible to get the ID of the row over and under the current selected row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Object currentRow = table.getValue(); //current selected row

Object nextRow = table.nextItemId(currentRow);
Object previousRow = table.prevItemId(currentRow);
```